# TCP application on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-worker-roles

I need to develop an application that is based directly on **TCP** (so I cant use Http).

I would like to deploy it on Azure but I cant find the right "app type" to use. Web applications do not support TCP (http only) and Worker Roles are now deprecated.

Is **service fabric cluster** what I need?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, but that may be a bit too much, look at [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/) or [ACI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) first.

Comment: By the way _"Worker Roles are now deprecated."_, they're not deprecated, they're just no longer recommended for new projects given their ASM (Azure Service Manager API) heritage. If a Worker Role fits your project, use it and don't look back.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Azure Web Apps can't work with TCP.

Your options are IaaS using Virtual Machines or using containers on Azure Container Instances.